# Total number of arguments in a command

Tags: totalcount

I want to write a command with two arguments that accepts text and a mark (a real value), respectively. How can I automatically compute the sum of marks for use elsewhere in the document?

```
\newcounter{num}
\newcommand{\soal}[2]{
    \stepcounter{num} \thenum & {#1} & {#2} \\[4pt] \hline
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer
I want the total score to be written elsewhere, for example, the end of the table and the scores can be real numbers if you guide me thanks

Answer (score 2):

### **Updated Answer:**

This answer allows you to access the total anywhere from the document and for adding real values.

[image: New Output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calculator}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{firstTime}                      % Declare a new variable of type boolean
\setboolean{firstTime}{true}                % Set it to true
\newcounter{num}

\newcommand{\soal}[2]{
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{firstTime}}{       % If first time, add 0 + (passed number)
        \ADD{0}{#2}{\totalMarks}            % Perform the actual calculation
        \setboolean{firstTime}{false}       % Set the boolean variable to false
    }{                                      % Else, a total exists, so add passed number
        \ADD{\totalMarks}{#2}{\totalMarks}  % Perform the actual calculation
    }
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        \stepcounter{num} \thenum & {#1} & \totalMarks \\[4pt] \hline
    \end{tabular}\par
}
\begin{document}
    \soal{Started at two and $\frac{1}{2}$}{2.50}
    \soal{Added three and $\frac{1}{4}$}{3.25}
    \soal{Added five and $\frac{3}{4}$}{5.75}\par~\\[2ex]
    Now, for the total marks: \totalMarks
\end{document}
```

---

### **Original Answer:**

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{num}
\newcounter{total}

\newcommand{\soal}[2]{
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        \stepcounter{num} \thenum & {#1} & \addtocounter{total}{#2} \thetotal \\[4pt] \hline
    \end{tabular}\par
}
\begin{document}
    \soal{Started at two}{2}
    \soal{Added three}{3}
    \soal{Added five}{5}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer
I want to the total point to be written elsewhere, for example, the end of the table and the point can be real numbers if you guide me thanks

Comment: I have updated the answer and from the looks of it, there is the exam [documentclass](https://ctan.org/pkg/exam?lang=en) that I highly suggest you use because it is what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks a lot and best regards